# Move inline comments to the previous line

Tags: python, regex

```
from re import compile, MULTILINE, sub

data= """\
 # comment1
key1=value1
key2=value2 # comment2
key3=value3 # comment3 #"""

print("----------------------- before sub")
print(data)
print("----------------------- after")
print(sub(compile("^(.*)(#.*)$", MULTILINE), "\\2\\n\\1", data).strip())
```

Do you think it is possible to do better (only one line)?
Result

```
------------------------- before sub
 # comment1
key1=value1
key2=value2 # comment2
key3=value3 # comment3 #
------------------------- after
# comment1

key1=value1
# comment2
key2=value2 
#
key3=value3 # comment3
```

I do not know do better.
As you see, **only the comment 2 is properly treated** (except space at end of line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  `^(\s*\S+\s*)(#[^\n]*)` and replace by `\1\n\2`.

```
print(re.sub(r"^(\s*\S+\s*)(#[^\n]*)", re.MULTILINE), r"\2\n\1", data)
```

[See demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/28#python)

Comment: I guess i will have to take it upon myself to leave booze for 2 weeks if i miss that and it wont happen again :P

Comment: I remember this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28885651/4099593 I had just upvoted and left. But today I had to do some work before pressing the ^ button :)

Comment: Great, is perfect but it must pass through compiles otherwise it will not work. print(sub(compile(r"^(\s*\S+\s*)(#[^\n]*)", MULTILINE), r"\2\n\1", data).strip()). Thanks a lot.